# Rotate chart title in Echarts?

Tags: echarts

In Apache Echarts, is there a way to rotate the title text of a chart so that it is vertically oriented on one side rather than horizontal on the top? The title at the top sometimes takes important chart real-estate that my series in some cases can overlap. I would like to instruct Echarts when there's a space crunch to move the title off to the left side in a vertical position (like reading titles on the spines of books in a library). There appears to be several "rotate" options for labels, but nothing for titles.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you can rotate the main title if you use the default **canvas renderer**. In this case, you may want to play with the name of your `yAxis` like this:

```js
const myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

let option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    name: 'This is my title',
    nameLocation: 'center',
    nameRotate: 90,
    nameGap: 45,
    nameTextStyle: {
      color: 'black',
      fontSize: 18,
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      type: 'line'
    }
  ]
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```

Alternatively, you could use the **SVG renderer** and add a bit of CSS to transform the main title (which is a `<text>` element):

```js
const myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'), null, { renderer: 'svg' });

let option = {
  title: {
    text: 'This is my title'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      type: 'line'
    }
  ]
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}

svg g text:last-child {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-250px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for these great suggestions. I'll have to give them a try soon.